# What are the differences between memory management in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

How does one dynamically allocate memory for an array of `const char*`s? That is, for example, `const char** array = /* ??? */`. I know `malloc` is similar to `new` in C++, but always returns a `void*`.

More broadly, what are the differences between how memory management is handled in C vs C++? For example, what things do I have to watch out for in C that someone may not think about in C++?

Comment: The difference in memory management between C and C++ is that C++ pretends to have some. :-)

Comment: in C++ `std::vector<const char *> v(N);` . Although it would be bad style to use `const char *` in the first place

Comment: As evidence of what @M.M just said, consider [this issued I opened](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/issues/773) for [pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) just a couple of days ago (the fix is [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/merge_requests/216/diffs?commit_id=b94dba9dafe41caf374e55fba2af242a41f97e5b)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allocate the array, you would do something like this:

```
const char **array = malloc( x * sizeof( char * ) );
```

Then allocate each element of the array.

```
if ( array )
    for ( int i = 0; i < x; ++i )
        array[i] = malloc( y * sizeof( char ) );
else
    printf( "malloc failed :(" );
```

`malloc` returns a `void*` but it's compatible with other pointer types.

In both C and C++ you need to manage the memory yourself, but C does not have things like `unique_ptr` -- also, no `new` and `delete`, use `malloc` and `free`. There's also `calloc` and `realloc`.

`malloc` can return `NULL` in the case when it fails, so you *should* check for that too. Note that it doesn't throw like `new` can in C++. More information on `malloc` can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

As requested, when freeing up the array, you basically just do the same thing in reverse. Noting that [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) does not take in a size, just the pointer. The `free` function will ignore `NULL` pointers, so you don't have to worry about that here.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < x; ++i )
   free( array[i] );
free( array );
```

Of course, as in C++, don't double `free` memory. That is bad. :)

Comment: C is also devoid of conveniences like `std::vector` and `std::map` which can do a lot of memory management for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; it's written well and straightforward. Is there any way you could also include the deallocation process?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson added.

Comment: Howcome you check the result of the first malloc but not the later ones?

Comment: @M.M., no particular reason. Was just an example.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between `malloc` and `new` is that `new` will call the default constructor for the allocated object, if applicable. This is one reason why mixing these two in C++ is very bad practice.

`malloc` requires you to check the return value for NULL to check if it fails, whereas `new` will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception out in the wild when it fails.

Another big difference is that C++ has the memory leak operator `new[]`, which allocates an array that will leak when one yet again accidentally uses `delete` rather than `delete[]`.

C++ also allows you to overload these operators - valid cases of when you need to do this exist, but mostly it is wildly questionable practice.

Manual memory allocation in C++ is mostly frowned upon, for good reasons. You'd rather use `std::string` in this case and let that class worry about memory allocation. Alterntatively you could use a smart pointer class to do the deallocation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another Memory management aspect that is present in C++ but not in C, is that C++ have object oriented approach to classes . When an instance gets created the constructor of that instance is called, when that instance goes out of scope the destructor is called, this behavior is automated by the compiler, and is transparent to the programmer.

Therefore, it is good practice to run dynamic memory de allocation in the destructor, to ensure that any dynamic memory allocated by the instance is freed when the instance is no longer in scope.

Constructor and desctructor concept only present in C++ and not in C.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the concept, this is what's referred to as [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) (I know, the name doesn't help).

Comment: "it is good practice to run dynamic memory de allocation in the destructor" And not only there. "Rule of three".